# Why subtract 'a'

Tags: java

can someone explain what this line of code does ?

```
for(k=0; k < limit; k++)
{
    int index = s.charAt(k) - 'a';     <---> THIS LINE
}
t.myIsWord = true;
```

why is is - 'a' ? I don't understand

Comment: When you run it in a debugger, what does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int index = s.charAt(k) - 'a';
```

In Java char can be casted to int. Each character has some int value, but it's not true that 'a' is 0 and 'b' is 1. Those values are different (based on position in ASCII table).

To get 'a' as 0, 'b' as 1, etc. you need to subtract 'a' from given character.

This is what this line does.

Answer (score 7):

It converts `'a'` to `0`, `'b'` to `1`, `'c'` to `2` and so on...